# Thinking to die

Tags: hadith, death, health

I had some lecture on YouTube from Muhammad hoblos about death, so in that video he try to explain that when you remember death your problem become solved.

Since then I started thinking of how people die just like that until I start thinking of what the dead are facing in the grave and will they now know the truth, but know it get worst I have start thinking maybe I should die now and know all what am being thinking about.

So am afraid of what am thinking maybe is right or not please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

peace be upon those who follow guidance,

> So am afraid of what am thinking maybe is right or not please help me

**quran**:

saying of الله the most high:

> وَاتَّقُوا يَوْمًا تُرْجَعُونَ فِيهِ إِلَى اللَّهِ ۖ ثُمَّ تُوَفَّىٰ
> كُلُّ نَفْسٍ مَّا كَسَبَتْ وَهُمْ لَا يُظْلَمُونَ (281)
>
> [البقرة](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/translations/english/47.html?a=288)
>
> (281) And fear a Day when you will be returned to Allah. Then every
> soul will be compensated for what it earned, and they will not be
> treated unjustly.

**hadith**:

the prophet محمد ﷺ said:

> "‏ أَكْثِرُوا ذِكْرَ هَاذِمِ اللَّذَّاتِ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ يَعْنِي الْمَوْتَ ‏.‏
>
> [ابن ماجة](https://sunnah.com/urn/1343980)
>
> وَالَّذِي نَفْسِي بِيَدِهِ إِنْ لَوْ تَدُومُونَ عَلَى مَا تَكُونُونَ
> عِنْدِي وَفِي الذِّكْرِ لَصَافَحَتْكُمُ الْمَلاَئِكَةُ عَلَى
> فُرُشِكُمْ وَفِي طُرُقِكُمْ وَلَكِنْ يَا حَنْظَلَةُ سَاعَةً وَسَاعَةً
> ‏"‏ ‏.‏ ثَلاَثَ مَرَّاتٍ ‏.
>
> [مسلم](https://sunnah.com/muslim/50/14)

what i know from knowledgeable people is to collect between hadiths not take one and leave other when both are correct and trusted by fair narrators.

**hadith**:

the prophet محمد ﷺ said:

> اَللَّهُمَّ أَصْلِحْ لِي دِينِي اَلَّذِي هُوَ عِصْمَةُ أَمْرِي,
> وَأَصْلِحْ لِي دُنْيَايَ اَلَّتِي فِيهَا مَعَاشِي, وَأَصْلِحْ لِي
> آخِرَتِي اَلَّتِي إِلَيْهَا مَعَادِي, وَاجْعَلْ اَلْحَيَاةَ زِيَادَةً
> لِي فِي كُلِّ خَيْرٍ, وَاجْعَلْ اَلْمَوْتَ رَاحَةً لِي مِنْ كُلِّ
> شَرٍّ
>
> [مسلم](https://sunnah.com/urn/2118840)